# error with creating a round_up(float) function in C

Tags: c, function, rounding

I am trying to write a round_up function that converts a float number to integer, but there seems to be error with my way of getting the decimal digits (the remainder of float number % 1). If the float number is 4.4, I wish to convert it to 4; if it's 4.5, I wish to convert it to 5.
 **Error message: error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘float’ and ‘int’)**

```
int round_up(float x)
{
    int remainder;
    int ret_whole_num;

    ret_whole_num = x/1;
    remainder = x % 1.0;   /* this causes errors */

    if (remainder > 5) 
        return ret_whole_num += 1;

    return ret_whole_num;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the `round` function? -- floats/doubles don't have a remainder operator you can use.

Comment: My assignment does not allow using math.h, this is just a tiny part of my assignment that is to implement a synch barrier algorithm (dissemination)

Comment: Please change round_up to round_half_up, or mention it in the question body. People think that you're trying to implement `ceil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
int round_zero_digits(float x)
{
  return x + 0.5;
}
```

Or more general:

```
#include <math.h> /* for pow()  */

...

float round_n_digits(float x, unsigned int n)
{
  x *= pow(10., n);

  x = (int) (x + 0.5);

  while (n--)
  {
    x /=10.;
  }

  return x;
}
```

With `round_n_digits(x, 0)` being equivalent to `round_zero_digits(x)`.

**Update (not using the `math` lib):**

```
float round_n_digits(float x, unsigned int n)
{
  unsigned int n_save = n;

  while (n--)
  {
    x *= 10.;
  }

  x = (int) (x + 0.5);

  while (n_save--)
  {
    x /= 10.;
  }

  return x;
}
```

---

**Update^2 (the pure C'ish way):**

```
#define ROUND_ZERO_DIGITS(x) ((int) ((x) + 0.5))

float round_n_digits(float x, unsigned int n)
{
  unsigned int n_save = n;

  while (n--)
  {
    x *= 10.;
  }

  x = ROUND_ZERO_DIGITS(x);

  while (n_save--)
  {
    x /= 10.;
  }

  return x;
}
```

With `ROUND_ZERO_DIGITS()` being the macro'ed version of the function `round_zero_digits()`.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Sure? Did you test this?

Comment: The function supplied is correct. If `x` is `0.4`, then `x + 0.5` is `0.9`. The `return` statement implicitly casts to the return type, which is `int`, and implicit casts will truncate this to `0`, which is what you want. An explicit cast (e.g. `return (int)(x + 0.5);`) might have been clearer. If you want to pick holes in it you might consider whether the rounding for `-0.5` is what you expect.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin The question header is misleading. Round up should be "round half up", and this is the correct solution.

Comment: 0.4 should be rounded down to 0, which is right based on alk's solution. Thanks.

Comment: @alk, thanks very much. Your answer is very elegant!

Comment: @user3125367 Oh... Well it is **truly** misleading, you wouldn't ever call *proper rounding* as *round_up*.

Comment: @user3125367: the name says round_up and not just round, so it should convert 0.4 also to 1.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, but this is inconsistent with the question body. *If the float number is 4.4, I wish to convert it to 4; if it's 4.5, I wish to convert it to 5.* This is definitely half-up. (And `ceil` is already there.)

Comment: What exactly does the `round_n_digits` do?

Comment: The (just) corrected version of `round_n_digits(42.34, 1)` will be `42.3` and `round_n_digits(42.45, 1)` will be `42.5`. Thanks for notifying... :-) @ThoAppelsin It'll round the n-th digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int round_up(float x)
{
    if ( (int) x == x ) return x;
    else return x + 1;
}
```

Comment: `0.` would return `1`.

Comment: `0.1` would return `1`, which still does not match the questioned result?

Comment: @Joe Not a problem bro

Comment: @alk As noted in the comments, we came up with the answer with the idea that it is round_up. If it is only half_up (round), then I agree with your answer of + 0.5